# SAPUI5 'Save' Button Form with 2 views

Tags: javascript, xml, button, sapui5

Good morning,I am new in SAPUI5 and I'm trying to make an easy exercise. I got it almost done but I would like to implement a save button to save data. Right now I have a Responsive Table which shows some names with surnames and some other information. When I click on any item, it goes to another view in which I have a form. In this form, the data is shown. But if I change it there (without pressing the button), the information changes also in the previous view. I also have a 'Save' button but I don't know how to implement it in a way that only when I change the input values of the form and press the button, it saves it and returns me to the first view, with the info updated.

The program looks like this:

First view:
[image: Image 1]

Second view with form:
[image: Image 2]

So as I said, is there any way in which I could change for example the name in the second view and only when I press the 'Save' (Guardar) button it updates in the first view? Thank you so much in advance.

Here's the code in my GitHub if you want to download it:
https://github.com/DarkIceDust/webapp

---

ListaUsuarios.view.xml (the first view):

```
<mvc:View
   controllerName="sap.ui.demo.walkthrough.controller.ListaUsuarios"
   xmlns="sap.m"
   xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
   <Table
      id="listaUsuarios"
      headerText="{i18n>TituloListaUsuarios}"
      class="sapUiResponsiveMargin"
      width="auto"
      items="{usuarios>/Usuarios}" >
      <headerToolbar>
         <Toolbar>
            <Title text="{i18n>TituloListaUsuarios}"/>
            <ToolbarSpacer/>
            <SearchField width="50%" search=".buscarUsuarios"/>
         </Toolbar>
      </headerToolbar>
      <columns>
        <Column
            hAlign="End"
            minScreenWidth="Small"
            demandPopin="true"
            width="4em">
            <Text text="{i18n>TituloNombre}"/>
        </Column>
        <Column
            hAlign="End"
            minScreenWidth="Small"
            demandPopin="true"
            width="4em">
            <Text text="{i18n>TituloApellidos}"/>
        </Column>
        <Column
            hAlign="End"
            minScreenWidth="Small"
            demandPopin="true"
            width="4em">
            <Text text="{i18n>TituloTelefono}"/>
        </Column>
        <Column
            hAlign="End"
            minScreenWidth="Small"
            demandPopin="true"
            width="4em">
            <Text text="{i18n>TituloCorreo}"/>
        </Column>
        <Column
            hAlign="End"
            minScreenWidth="Small"
            demandPopin="true"
            width="4em">
            <Text text="{i18n>TituloFecha}"/>
        </Column>
      </columns>
      <items>
         <ColumnListItem
            type="Navigation"
            press="onPress">
            <cells>
                <ObjectIdentifier title="{usuarios>Nombre}"/>
                <Text text="{usuarios>Apellidos}"/>
                <ObjectNumber number="{usuarios>Telefono}" emphasized="false"/>
                <Text text="{usuarios>Correo}"/>
                <Text text="{usuarios>FechaNacimiento}"/>
            </cells>
         </ColumnListItem>
      </items>
   </Table>
</mvc:View>
```

---

ListaUsuarios.controller.js (the controller for this first view):

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
    "sap/ui/model/Filter",
    "sap/ui/model/FilterOperator"
    ], function ( Controller, JSONModel, Filter, FilterOperator ) {
        "use strict";
        return Controller.extend("sap.ui.demo.walkthrough.controller.ListaUsuarios", {
        
        buscarUsuarios : function (oEvent) {

            // Construye el filtro del array
            var aFilter = [];
            var sQuery = oEvent.getParameter("query");
            if (sQuery) {
                aFilter.push(new Filter("Nombre", FilterOperator.Contains, sQuery));
            }

            // Enlace de filtros
            var oList = this.byId("listaUsuarios");
            var oBinding = oList.getBinding("items");
            oBinding.filter(aFilter);
        },
        
        onPress: function (oEvent) {
            var oItem = oEvent.getSource();
            var oRouter = this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter();
            oRouter.navTo("detail", {
                rutaUsuarios: window.encodeURIComponent(oItem.getBindingContext("usuarios").getPath().substr(1))
            });
        }
    });

});
```

---

Detail.view.xml (the XML for the second view where the form is):

```
<mvc:View
    controllerName="sap.ui.demo.walkthrough.controller.Detail"
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
    <Page
        id="page"
        title="{i18n>TituloDetalles}"
        showNavButton="true"
        navButtonPress=".onNavBack">
        <ObjectHeader
            title="Introduzca sus nuevos datos, por favor."/>
                <Text text="{i18n>TituloNombre}"/>
                <Input
                    value="{usuarios>Nombre}"/>
                <Text text="{i18n>TituloApellidos}"/>
                <Input
                    value= "{usuarios>Apellidos}"/>
                <ObjectNumber number="{i18n>TituloTelefono}" emphasized="false"/>
                <Input
                    value= "{usuarios>Telefono}"/>
                <Text text="{i18n>TituloCorreo}"/>
                <Input
                    type="Email"
                    value= "{usuarios>Correo}"/>
                <Text text="{i18n>TituloFecha}"/>
                <Input
                    type="Date"
                    value= "{usuarios>FechaNacimiento}"/>
                <Button
                    text="{i18n>BotonGuardar}"
                    press=".onSave"/>
                <Button
                    text="{i18n>BotonCancelar}"
                    press=".onNavBack"/>
    </Page>
</mvc:View>
```

---

Detail.controller.js (the controller for the second view):

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "sap/ui/core/routing/History"
], function (Controller, History) {
    "use strict";

    return Controller.extend("sap.ui.demo.walkthrough.controller.Detail", {
        onInit: function() {
            var oRouter = this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter();
            oRouter.getRoute("detail").attachPatternMatched(this._onObjectMatched, this);
        },
        _onObjectMatched: function (oEvent) {
            this.getView().bindElement({
                path: "/" + window.decodeURIComponent(oEvent.getParameter("arguments").rutaUsuarios),
                model: "usuarios"
            });
        },
        
        onNavBack: function () {
            var oHistory = History.getInstance();
            var sPreviousHash = oHistory.getPreviousHash();

            if (sPreviousHash !== undefined) {
                window.history.go(-1);
            } else {
                var oRouter = this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter();
                oRouter.navTo("overview", {}, true);
            }
        },
        onSave: function(){
            
        }
    
    });
});
```

Comment: Perhaps create a new named model called "newEntry" and bind the input controls to that. Once you hit save you append the new entity from this model to the model holding the total collection. If you are wanting to persist to a data store then round-trip to your backend. Let me know if you need more detail.

Comment: I'm doing it with a local JSON Model, so it's even easier. I understand what you said, but if you can tell me more details i would really appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another take on your issue.

What you are looking for is Dirty state ... I don't think JSONModel has that capability. But you can simulate that yourself.

```
        _onObjectMatched: function (oEvent) {
            this.route = "/" + window.decodeURIComponent(oEvent.getParameter("arguments").rutaUsuarios);
            this.getView().bindElement({
                path: this.route,
                model: "usuarios"
            });
            this.oOldData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.getView().getModel("usuarios").getProperty(this.route)));
        },
        
        onNavBack: function (oEvent) {
            
            // Check if it's dirty
            if (this.oOldData !== this.getView().getModel("usuarios").getProperty(this.route)) {
                this.getView().getModel("usuarios").setProperty(this.route, this.oOldData);
            }
            
            var oHistory = History.getInstance();
            var sPreviousHash = oHistory.getPreviousHash();

            if (sPreviousHash !== undefined) {
                window.history.go(-1);
            } else {
                var oRouter = this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter();
                oRouter.navTo("overview", {}, true);
            }
        },
        onSave: function(){
            this.oOldData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.getView().getModel("usuarios").getProperty(this.route)));
            debugger
        }
```

In fact, if you want to be more courteous, you can put a confirmation dialog and upon confirmation, revert the data and return back or else don't navigate.

Answer (score 0):

Initialise the relevant models.

Use newUser model in your XML View (Detail.view.xml):

```
<mvc:View
    controllerName="sap.ui.demo.walkthrough.controller.Detail"
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
    <Page
        id="page"
        title="{i18n>TituloDetalles}"
        showNavButton="true"
        navButtonPress=".onNavBack">
        <ObjectHeader
            title="Introduzca sus nuevos datos, por favor."/>
                <Text text="{i18n>TituloNombre}"/>
                <Input placeholder="Insert Number"
                       value="{newUser>Nombre}"/>
                <Text text="{i18n>TituloApellidos}"/>
                <Input
                    value= "{newUser>Apellidos}"/>
                <ObjectNumber number="{i18n>TituloTelefono}" emphasized="false"/>
                <Input
                    value= "{newUser>Telefono}"/>
                <Text text="{i18n>TituloCorreo}"/>
                <Input
                    type="Email"
                    value= "{newUser>Correo}"/>
                <Text text="{i18n>TituloFecha}"/>
                <Input
                    type="Date"
                    value= "{newUser>FechaNacimiento}"/>
                <Button
                    text="{i18n>BotonGuardar}"
                    press=".onSave"/>
                <Button
                    text="{i18n>BotonCancelar}"
                    press=".onNavBack"/>
    </Page>
</mvc:View>
```

In your Detail.controller.js:

```
onSave: function(){
    var newUser = this.getView().getModel("newUser").getProperty("/");
    var users = this.getView().getModel("usuarios").getProperty("/");
    users.push(newUser);
    this.getView().getModel("usuarios").setProperty("/", users);
}
```